# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded swift mailer

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, swiftmailer

I am using swift mailer using this statement:

```
  require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
```

to send email.

It was working fine for many months and now suddenly I start getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
 ...\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 271
```

I don't know why this error suddenly comes up and no emails are being sent. I have done nothing, it just stop suddenly. Also I own the server and I have made no changes to this server.

*Actually the file called to send email is by jquery and I see in firebug that it calls the file properly but when it calls the file to send email, it gives this error after some time.*

Thanks

Comment: What's swiftmailer using for an SMTP server? If it's a remote one, there could be a problem establishing a connection, causing the whole script to time out.

Comment: i have whole lib directory of SwiftMailer on same domain and yes its web server and all other domains are working fine.

Comment: No... not web server. What SMTP sever (and where) is Swiftmailer connecting to? Swift itself doesn't send mail, it just hands them over to the SMTP server, and it's that connection that's most likely timing out.

Comment: its connecting to same server SMTP

Comment: Do you manage a mailing list? Is is possible that you list has grown in size and now it takes over 30 seconds to send out all the emails?

Comment: its just sending one email but trying to open one php file as template and then send email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain that nothing else has changed, is it possible it now takes longer then 30 seconds to send the email? The 30 second maximum can be adjusted in PHP, either globally in php.ini or per request. While generally not recommended to increase this in a production environment, typically it is ok for back end jobs like sending mails out.

You can change it by doing: ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

Set to 0 for infinite time, although if you have a real problem on the server, your request may not ever complete.

Comment: same thing. do you think there can be any permission issue when trying to read template file with $Content = file_get_contents($temp_page))

Comment: @air What is `line 271` of `...\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php`?

Comment: if (!$this->_stream = stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, stream_context_create($options)))
    {
      throw new Swift_TransportException(
        'Connection could not be established with host ' . $this->_params['host'] .
        ' [' . $errstr . ' #' . $errno . ']'
        );
    }

Comment: Ok so you are timing out connecting to the SMTP server. Any firewall rules change recently? Or did you start some other service on the port that you were using for SMTP?